# FET amplifier from 100 kHz to 100 MHz

Tags: amplifier, rf, fet

I studied electronics a long time ago (and forgot almost everything) but now I would like to make a FET amplifier up to 100 MHz of extremely small signals (e.g. 1nV or even smaller.) The signals are so small that an opamp (I believe) is not possible to use. I would like to simulate it first (ngspice or LTspice) and then actually build it.

I know the noise level will also be around some nV, but please let us assume I work with extremely low temperatures and this is not an issue.

Power efficiency is not an issue (could be 1% if needed) and power supply could be at 20-30 V if needed.

I though about using a cascade amplifier with one FET and one BJT NPN with a current source driven by 2x BJT PNP transistors (using a current mirror). This works well up to ~1 MHz, but not to 100 MHz. I believe my problem is finding a good FET transistor. Maybe a GaAsFET would work.

A good starting place was this circuit:
https://www.designworldonline.com/cascode-amplifiers-2/
It does not use a current source, but close enough.

The [FET](https://pt.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Broadcom-Avago/ATF-34143-BLKG?qs=RuhU64sK2%252Bt35SXiAk9qwg%3D%3D) is no longer for sale.

I actually don't understand resistor R5 in this circuit. Since the transistor is a FET, isn't the gate current zero? Why is R5 there?
I simulated this circuit (using the linear spice model) and I see that R5 does make quite a difference in the spectrum, hence I can only conclude that it is because we are using the linear spice model and not an accurate model (it doesn't seem to have V_th for example.) I think I'm missing something.

[image: cascade circuit with passive]

I guess my main problem is how to find a good FET transistor that:

- Works from 100 kHz to 100 MHz (with a good gain). If this is not possible, then at least from 1 MHz to 80 MHz would be nice.
- Has a "full" spice model (not just the linear model since I want to see the transient response.)
- Is currently being sold (not deprecated.)
  If there is a better way to design this amplifier please let me know.

Comment: Crucial questions at these frequencies and levels. What is the output impedance of your source? What is the input impedance of your load? Do you really want to build - perhaps for learning, or for fun, or for value engineering if you need to make commercial quantities of them, or can you buy?

Comment: Where are you getting the terms "linear model" and "full model" from?  I've never encountered them before.  If you can, link us (or paste as a code block in the question) the model you used for the ATF-34143 so we can get a better idea of what you're trying to say.

Comment: What do you want to do with the amplified signal? Because if you have 80 MHz (that's 69 dBHz) of bandwidth, then good ole Johnson-Nyquist Thermal Noise tells us you'll have -174 dBm/Hz + 69 dBHz = -105 dBm as noise input power (at 20°C). A 1nV amplitude signal, depending on over which impedance that Nanovolt exists, will have less power. Which is fine if you can deal with it, but just so you know that what you're building comes with signal-theoretical challenges, not only practical challenges

Comment: You have a PHEMT there, not a JFET. They have a huge amount of gate leakage (in this case as much as 0.3mA). As far as AC performance goes, 3 pF of gate capacitance (drain and source  are effectively grounded in your cascode) will result in about 500Ω input impedance at 100MHz so 250Ω will make a difference. It's probably better to think of noise in terms of nV/rt(Hz) bandwidth. The 250Ω resistance (if at room temperature) will have a fair bit of J-N noise (about 20uV RMS over 100MHz BW). It's possible to achieve 1nV/rt(Hz) approximately levels with care at room temperature.

Comment: _"since the transistor is a FET, isn't the gate current zero?"_ - At DC, yes, but definitely not at 100MHz.

Comment: I'm super curious: 100 MHz @ 1nV -- what's it for?

Comment: For such a "large" bandwidth (max/min=1000), one can perhaps use also a "modulated" approach as used in the first stages of the analog spectrum analyzers (depending on a "particular" signal).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Now I understand the 250 Ohms...I'm actually a little embarrassed I didn't catch that the gate current isn't zero at some MHz. Regarding noise -> you are right, but lets assume (for now at least) that I'm working at 70K (instead of 200K) so noise level is far below -174 dBm/Hz.

Comment: Regarding the impedance, I don't have to match it with the 50 Ohms (or anything of the kind, at least I don't think so). Since the signal is so low I will probably use the cascode in multiple stages to amplify from 1nV to 1mV. I want to build this system but this is NOT for commercial use. I don't plan on selling anything so the design doesn't need to be perfectly efficient/low cost/etc.

Comment: Regarding the "linear model", I took that from a HPRF.LIB spice model for the ATF10170 where it says:**********
* Library of GaAs Mesfet Models from H-P
*
* IMPORTANT NOTE: The models in this library are linear ONLY.
* They may only be used with the AC and DC analyses. Do not use
* them in the Transient analysis.
* 
* This file includes die models (those subcircuits that end with
* the number 00) and die models connected to various package models.
* When the die is connected to the package model, only the lead 
* inductance from the package model is used.
**********
etc etc etc

Comment: How can one acquire this `HPRF.LIB` file?  Where did you get it from?

Comment: https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/model-parameters/models_ugr.7z -> inside it you will find the HPRF.LIB.

Comment: Ah, great. Thank you. It makes perfect sense now. If you notice, those HP subcircuit MESFET models denoted as "linear" are made purely out of linear components (see leading character of each line): R's (resistors), L's (inductors), C's (capacitors), and G's (transconductances). They are used to manually make a small signal model. This is quite atypical (I've never seen it) since what you usually do with SPICE is use the built-in non-linear models and when you choose to do a small signal analysis (`.AC`), it will find the operating point and calculate the small signal equivalent automatically.

Comment: Therefore I believe what you're looking for are SPICE models/subcircuits which use an intrinsic MESFET model. [LTspice](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp/html/Z-device.htm) and [ngspice](https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/docs/ngspice-html-manual/manual.xhtml#magicparlabel-12395) use a similar model syntax whereas PSpice models use a different one ([see page 108](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/PSpice_ReferenceguideOrCAD.pdf)). It's also possible someone could build a subcircuit using behavorial sources and non-linear capacitances. Anyway, the takeaway is avoid the RLCG models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before, take a look to [this](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-06838/data-sheets/5968-0161.pdf) and [this](https://www.emelectronics.co.uk/ultra-low-level-dc-voltage-amplifiers/dc-nanovolt-amplifier-model-a10/).

Perhaps a "distributed" amplifier should do it or [minicircuits](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/Amplifiers.html?subcategories=Low%20Noise%20Amplifier) [RAM-8A](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/RAM-8A+.pdf).
For reference, an example with "bad" BJT transistors.

[image]

It is perhaps what you don't expect, but here is a circuit that could be tested (100 kHz -> 20 MHz).
Testing in the nV range is really a challenge, so good luck ...

[image]

Tried also something like analog "spectrum analyzer".
1 nV input -> something like 8 uV output.

[image]

And here, the behavior with square waves (1 uV) and recalculated filters. Not bad ...

[image]

See this for comparison with the input stages an ["old" spectrum analyzer](https://download.tek.com/manual/070909606.pdf), page 9-2.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for you answer. I will take a look at that BJT for sure. However I have the problem of the input impedance since the signal is very low at 1 nV (or even lower). The AC analysis seems great but the transient is terrible...

Comment: TRansient depends on some components and "bandwidth" as a "filter". So define exactly the specs of "signal".

Comment: I stand corrected. I just simulated your circuit and Vo follows Vi (assuming no noise, of course). Sorry for doubting you. I incorrectly thought that ib would always be zero in FET and non zero in BJT but that is only true at DC, which is far from 10 MHz. I don't exactly the spec of signal (I'm kind of new to this). I want it coming from an antenna and then passing through a mixer so I guess the input impedance for this circuit is ~200 Ohm and @1 nV peak to peak. I would be happy with a bandwidth from 1MHz to ~80 MHz. But as minimum up to 40 MHz.

Comment: I also imagine having multiple stages (Q1+Q2) could increase the gain (each stage would gain ~24 dB)? Could you also tell me if it is possible to increase the BW by lowering the gain? If so, which component should I change? Thank you again!

Comment: No worries. If your signal comes from an antenna and would pass through a mixer, then it is the "classic" schematic of the input stages of a "spectrum analyzer". And "generally" the amplifiers are after the multipliers. There can be as many as 3 multipliers and amplifiers. This is the principle of an HP spectrum analyzer I used ... many years ago. You should add these pieces of information to your question.

Comment: For low levels, the simpler is something like RAM-8A. Tried also something like "spectrum analyser". Will add in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This last circuit seems great! Can't wait to try it, but for now have a Merry Christmas!

Comment: The more I think about this last circuit, the happier I get :). Truly this is my Christmas gift :D. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hope that help. If you need more information ...

Comment: @Antonio51 - Why do you call this architecture a "spectrum analyser"?

Comment: The first stage is really the schematic of the input stage of an analog spectrum analyzer with the same specifications (LO and IF are all > Fmax signal for no interference). The only difference is that the IF frequency here is a "large" bandwidth (100 MHz), versus the spectrum analyzers where it is a "narrow" bandwidth at a higher frequency (for example of 2.2 GHz or more, depending of the max frequency of the signal to be analyzed) to allow a bandwidth of ~100 MHz and 2 other stages with multiplier and 2nd-3rd IF with selectable bandwidth ... for maximum sensitivity ...

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  But that architecture (up-convert, filter, down-convert) is used in many more applications than just spectrum analyzers.  By spectrum analyzer, I'm talking about a piece of test equipment.

Comment: Yes. Right. Used originally into the spectrum analyzer (or "heterodyne" receiver), unless I am wrong. This architecture is used because too much gain in one amplifier transforms surely that amplifier into an oscillator. A bigger gain may then be obtained easier by separating stages at different frequencies (50-60 dB per stage is "easy"). So two stages leads to 100-120 dB ... 3 stages are often used ... 150-180 dB gain (?) ... + digital filtering (?).